# How to use controller outside folder App\Http\Controllers in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a controller WebController at folder App\Web\Controllers\WebController.

> WebController

```php
<?php namespace App\Web\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class WebController extends Controller
{
    public index(){
        return view('layouts.master');
    }
}
```

> Route

```
Route::get('home_page','WebController@index');
```

When i call this route, the following error appears:

> Class App\Http\Controllers\WebController does not exist

Comment: default namespace is `App\Http\Controllers`. you need to custom it in RouteServiceProvider.php

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the routing system.

in `App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php` you will find the `map()` method:

```php
/**
     * Define the routes for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function map()
    {
        $this->mapWebRoutes();
        $this->mapApiRoutes();
    }
```

Down that class you will find the definition for the namespace of "Web Routes"

```php
/**
 * Define the "web" routes for the application.
 *
 * These routes all receive session state, CSRF protection, etc.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace($this->namespace) // 'App\Http\Controllers'
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

Now you just need to change the `namespace()` attribute to your liking

```php
protected function mapWebRoutes()
{
    Route::middleware('web')
         ->namespace('App\Web\Controllers')
         ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
}
```

Comment: How would this impact the default functionality? surely the default namespace is no longer used now?

Comment: @MHewison in any route in `routes/web.php`, like `Route::get('home_page','WebController@index');` would point to `App\Web\Controllers\WebController.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
class WebController extends **Controller**
```

There is a problem with this relationship. You have to import controller into this file. You are missing

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller
```

Also, you route is wrong. Try this

```
Route::namespace('your namespace here')->group(function () { 
   Route::get('/', 'your-controller-here@your-method'); 
 });
```

> Do not change the configuration of the routeserviceprovider

Comment: According to [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-group-namespaces) this is only meant for namespaces below `App/Http/Controllers`. Have you tested this? Will it work to define a new root namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You change default namespace in RouteServiceProvider.
`protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';`
`App\Http\Controllers` is default namespace you can change it to
`protected $namespace = 'App\Web\Controllers';`
and then your code should work

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest either the above code from Devetoka by using the namespace, or for only 1 or two controllers (in my case), you can simply inject the full namespace in. This is tested and works.

```
Route::get('home_page','\App\Web\Controllers\WebController@index');
```